# copy value from active sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to copy different value of current sheet (the sheet that I see in the moment that I start the script) to another sheet.

```
function printIng() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var actualSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var actualSheetName1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection();
  var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
  //Logger.log('Nome foglio'+nameRicetta);
  //var value = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  //Logger.log('nome ricetta:'+ value);
  //var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(dataRange);

  //TEST
  if(actualSheetName != "Indice Ricette" &&
     actualSheetName != "Template" &&
     actualSheetName != "Ingrediente" &&
     actualSheetName != "Impostazioni" &&
     actualSheetName != "Tipologia"){

       var nameRicetta = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('C4').getValue();
         //inserire if per decidere se creare ingrediente o no
         var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
         var result = ui.alert(
           'Please confirm',
           'Are you sure you want create'+ '['+ nameRicetta +'] ingredient?',
           ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

         // Process the user's response.
         if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
           Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
           var sheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Ingredienti"));
           var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
           //Select the column we will check for the first blank cell
           var columnToCheck = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
            // Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
           var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck)+1;

           sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'\!Y2');//nome
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,2,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'\!Y2');//nome
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'\!Y2');//nome

           sheet.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y2');//zucc
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,5,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y5');//gras
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,6,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y8');//sml
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,7,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y11');//as
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,8,1,1).setValue('0');
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,9,1,1).setValue('0');
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,10,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!S25');//pod rel
           sheet.getRange(lastRow,11,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Q25');//pac rel
         } else {
           Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
         }
       }
}
```

but the variable **actualSheetName** return always the first sheet (in this case is "Indice Ricette")

how can retrive the real current sheet?

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.getActivesSheet() returns the active sheet which is the one that you opened

Comment: I try: var actualSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var actualSheetName1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
but return the same "indice ricette" that there are the first sheet in the spreadsheet, but not the selected sheet that I see.

Comment: Can you provide an image of your spreadsheet so that we can see all of the tab/sheet names?

Comment: yes, I upload the screenshot

Comment: ```SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()``` sometimes does not work as expected. Try changing it by ```SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('NAME OF SHEET')``` or in case you want it to work on edit trigger use the ```onEdit(e)``` function and get the active sheet using e.source.getSheetByName('NAME OF SHEET');```. Let me know if that works :D

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a simpler example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast(e.range.getSheet().getName());
}

function abc() {  
  /do nothing
}
```

Copy the above functions to your script editor and save them. Then run abc() and if you need to authorize any scripts a dialog will pop up enabling your to do so.

Then create a couple of pages that you don't mind messing with.  And edit a cell in one of them.  A small dialog that's called a toast will appear in the lower right hand corner of the screen telling you what the name of the active page is.  It's always the page that you have edited.  You need to actually edit something on the page to get the onEdit(e) function to be triggered.

**Copying between sheets in one spreadsheet**

Here's an example that I did several years ago and I believe it took me about 4 hours and I just did it in about 30 minutes.  It's a complete example with a custom dialog giving you the ability to selection sheets and source range and destination range and copy from source to destination.  Have fun with it.

ah3.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
      input{margin:5px 2px 5px 0};
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <br /><select id="sel1" onchange="gotoSheet();"></select>
      <br /><input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Select Source Range" />
      <br /><input type="button" value="Save Source Range" onClick="saveFrom();"/>
      <br /><input type="text" id="to" placeholder="Selection Destination Range" />
      <br /><input type="button" value="Save Destination Range" onClick="saveTo(); "/>
      <br /><input type="button" value="Copy" onClick="doit()";/>
      <script>
        var gfrom={};
        var gto={};
        $(function(){
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
            updateSelect(vA);
          })
          .getSelections()
        });
         function updateSelect(vA,id){
           var id=id || 'sel1';
           vA.unshift('Please Select Sheet')
           var select = document.getElementById(id);
           select.options.length = 0; 
           for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
             select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
           }
        }
        function saveFrom() {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(fObj){
            $('#from').val(fObj.fromrange);
            gfrom=fObj;           
          })
          .saveFrom();
        }
        function saveTo() {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(tObj){
            $('#to').val(tObj.torange);
            gto=tObj;           
          })
          .saveTo();
        }
        function doit() {
          var cObj={};
          cObj['fromrg']=gfrom.fromrange;
          cObj['fromsh']=gfrom.fromsheet;
          cObj['torg']=gto.torange;
          cObj['tosh']=gto.tosheet;
          google.script.run.doIt(cObj);
        }
        function gotoSheet() {
          google.script.run.gotoSheet($('#sel1').val());
        }
        console.log('My Code');
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function saveFrom() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=ss.getActiveRange();
  return {fromsheet:sh.getName(),fromrange:rg.getA1Notation()};
}

function saveTo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=ss.getActiveRange();
  return {tosheet:sh.getName(),torange:rg.getA1Notation()};
}

function doIt(obj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fsh=ss.getSheetByName(obj.fromsh);
  var frg=fsh.getRange(obj.fromrg);
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName(obj.tosh);
  var trg=tsh.getRange(obj.torg);
  frg.copyTo(trg);
}

function getSelections() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var sA=shts.map(function(s){return s.getName();});
  return sA;
}

function gotoSheet(name) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheetByName(name).activate();
}

function copyRanges() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3'), "Copy From One Range to Another")
}
```

Running copyRanges kicks off the whole thing.

Animation:

[image]

This is how I think I'd rewrite your code.  But I'm guessing here a little because I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish.

```
function printIng() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ash=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ashname=ash.getName();
  var currentCell=ash.getActiveCell();
  if(ashname != "Indice Ricette" && ashname != "Template" && ashname != "Ingrediente" && ashname != "Impostazioni" && ashname != "Tipologia"){
```

I don't understand the purpose of the above conditional but it's clear that unless `case bianca` or some other sheetname other than the names in the if state is the active sheet then you never get here

```
    //The only sh that makes it to here is Base Bianca
    var nameRicetta=ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('C4').getValue();//so this makes no sense
    var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var result=ui.alert('Please confirm','Are you sure you want create'+ '['+ nameRicetta +'] ingredient?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Ingredienti");
      var dataRange=sh.getDataRange();
      var columnToCheck=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
      var lastRow=sh.getLastRow()+1;
      sh.getRange(lastRow,1,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'\!Y2');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,2,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'\!Y2');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'\!Y2');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y2');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,5,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y5');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,6,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y8');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,7,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Y11')
      sh.getRange(lastRow,8,1,1).setValue('0');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,9,1,1).setValue('0');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,10,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!S25');
      sh.getRange(lastRow,11,1,1).setFormula('='+ nameRicetta +'!Q25');
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your example, but I would like to know which is the real sheet selected, but not select the sheet that want to to copy

Comment: The one whose tab in highlighted

Comment: I tried to rewrite your code but I'm not really clear on what your trying to do here.

Comment: try to explain, I have some fixed sheet (red sheet) and new sheet (green) this sheet are  copyed starting from the Template Sheet, after copy the user can make some calculation inside the new sheet, after I need to copy some value from this sheet or another green (the user can select one green sheet from a lot of sheets) to the  sheet "Ingredienti". hope to be more clear now.... :-)